# How do I extract specific text values from a Genbank (.gb) file (Python, BioPython package)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

This may sound like a dumb question, but how do I extract a specific text value from a GenBank file?
I want to be able to take that text value and print that onto a separate text file but for now I just want to figure out how to retrieve that specific number.

[image: Text value I want to retrieve]

I was able to achieve this with the GenBank file ID by using some Biopython commands but I am very new to Biopython and cannot seem to figure a way to retrieve the CDS number.

[image: Code I used to retrieve GenBank file ID number]

[image: Output from code]

Answer (score 0):

The [`SeqRecord` object](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.SeqRecord.html#Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord) has additional attributes, among which `features` is a `list` of [`SeqFeature` objects](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.SeqFeature.html#Bio.SeqFeature.SeqFeature) and will be where CDS information would be stored (if present).

For example, the following would print the start location of all CDS features in a `SeqRecord`:

```python
for f in genbank_object.features:
  if f.type == "CDS":
    print(f.location.start.position)
```